# display two divs side-by-side with inline-block

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display two divs side-by-side with inline-block (can't use floats). Currently my CSS fails to do this. I realize this might be a duplicate, but having tried suggestions from related posts I still can't get it to work.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}
#images {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
#specs {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="images">
    TEST Data
  </div>

  <div id="specs">
    Test Data
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pro-tip: it can be easier for us to help you if you provide a jsfiddle; [i just put your code into one here](http://jsfiddle.net/onLmwh3a/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`#wrapper` must have `+200px` of width

Comment: sorry that was a mis-print. wrapper has width of 300px.

Comment: It's not possible, if `#wrapper` have 300px of width, that should works fine. are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Modify css for #wrapper:

```
#wrapper{
    display:inline-table;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Width must be at least 200px, since you want two elements (100px each) to fix within.

[example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bx2o77Ls/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your wrapper div is only 100px wide, so the two sub-items can't fit side by side since they're also 100px wide. I made it much wider and they now appear side by side: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onLmwh3a/2/)

```
#wrapper{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 300px;
}
#images {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
#specs {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

## wrapper is the same size as the contained elements #images and #specs, so make it width: 100% or something larger than 200px and those elements will line up horizontally.

```css
div {outline: 1px dashed red;}

#wrapper{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#images {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
#specs {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="images">
         TEST Data
     </div>

     <div id="specs">
         Test Data
     </div>
</div>
```